# How do I print all the values in this array

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, maps

```
Todo.map(item=>(
<><li>{item.Text}</li>
<li>{item.Todo}</li>
</>)
```

I was trying to Get value from firebase i used use state and got

```
Array(1)
0: {Text: 'Go Walk The Dog', Todo: 'Go Wash Dishes'}
```

I can print these values using .Field Name
But I dont want to specify the field name and also print additional value from use todo input

```
(2) [{…}, 'dasd']
0: {Text: 'Go Walk The Dog', Todo: 'Go Wash Dishes'}
1: "dasd"
```

Although i Can console log Todo to get this i dont know how to print it

Comment: Do you mean, you want to print "dasd" as a todo's text?

Comment: Nothing here shows interaction with Cloud Firestore, nor is it clear how `Todo` is populated, which makes it hard to say what's going wrong. I recommend reading: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).